# How to change the name of the toolbar for each activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json, xml

I want to know how to change the name of the toolbar for each Activity. And also I want to know how to center each name! 
Thanks!

Comment: `android:title`....

Comment: @SantanuSur Yes, but where do I have to write it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
   app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in your Activity

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
```

For Action Bar

```
setTitle("My new title");
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

on each Activities

Comment: Yes , but it set just one name for all the activities and I want a different names for each activity!

Comment: Do you mean Toolbar or ActionBar?

Comment: Toolbar. Not Toolbar (android.support.v7.widget) just Toolbar(android.widget).